# How to merge dataframe from 1D to 2D conditionally

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have a source dataframe included below (df) that I would like to reshape into a 2 dimensional dataframe (outputdf) with the first column as all unique values that exist in the df and a column for a select set of unique values in column B which I have loaded into a list (list). I would then populate this outputdf with the corresponding values in column c

df:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell A | 1 |
| Cell 2 | Cell A | 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell A | 3 |
| Cell 1 | Cell B | 4 |
| Cell 2 | Cell B | 5 |
| Cell 3 | Cell B | 6 |
| Cell 1 | Cell C | 7 |
| Cell 2 | Cell C | 8 |
| Cell 3 | Cell C | 9 |

list = [Cell A, Cell B)

I am unsure how to best do this in a looping manner as I would use this for a large dataframe with many entries. My goal would be something along the lines of the following though I know this logic would not work:

```
for x in list:
    outputdf[x] = outputdf.merge(df, on=['ColumnA', x], how='left').set_index('ColumnA')
```

to yield the following outputdf

outputdf:

| Column A | Cell A | Cell B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | 1 | 4 |
| Cell 2 | 2 | 5 |
| Cell 3 | 3 | 6 |

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot-table) method to turn values in Column B into columns and then use [rename_axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [droplevel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) to clean up the column names

test.csv

```
Column A,Column B,Column C
Cell 1,Cell A,1
Cell 2,Cell A,2
Cell 3,Cell A,3
Cell 1,Cell B,4
Cell 2,Cell B,5
Cell 3,Cell B,6
Cell 1,Cell C,7
Cell 2,Cell C,8
Cell 3,Cell C,9
```

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

table = pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'Column A', columns = ['Column B'])
table = table.rename_axis([None, None], axis=1)
table.columns = table.columns.droplevel()
```

The code would return like below

```
          Cell A  Cell B  Cell C
Column A                        
Cell 1         1       4       7
Cell 2         2       5       8
Cell 3         3       6       9
```